# How to append list of column to list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to add new column from csv to the table from the same csv. Im trying to use append but its still not working it says ''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = r"D:\python projects\volcano_data_2010.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(path)
data_used = data.iloc[:,[1,2,8,9]].values
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
data_used = imp.fit_transform(data_used) #so far ok
data_used = data_used.append([data.iloc[:,7].values])
print(data_used)
```

Comment: this is the dataset that im using https://www.kaggle.com/texasdave/volcano-eruptions i also already tried using np.append([data.iloc[:,7].values]) but it says append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'. i also tried np.append(np.reshape([data.iloc[:,7].values],(-1,1))) because i thought maybe it has something to do with the shape of the array but it didnt work too

Comment: How does your new column looks like? Can you give some examples and desired output dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

function append only applicable to list datatype, since your data type is in array use should use np.append but it will append array

```
a1 = np.append(data_used, data.iloc[:,7])
```

if you want to append like a columns, you should us np.column_stack function

```
a2 = np.column_stack((data_used, data.iloc[:,7]))
```